# how can I pass props to component attribute that takes parameters as an immutable string

Tags: reactjs

Hi I have this component that takes data-settings in this format I want to make value, min , unit etc to be variables for example a state or props I tried "value":{this.state.val} but not working

```
    <div className="eds-gauge" id={this.props.id}
                data-settings='{
                    "value":88 ,
                    "min": 0,
                    "max": 100,
                    "units": %,
                }'
                size={this.props.size}
            ></div>
```

how can I do it?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass your data as a string (looking as an object) probably you want to use [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

So your code would look something like

```
<div className="eds-gauge" id={this.props.id}
                data-settings={`{
                    "value":${this.state.value} ,
                    "min": ${this.state.min},
                    "max": ${this.state.max},
                    "units": ${this.state.units},
                }`}
                size={this.props.size}
            ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you should be using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
  <div
    className="eds-gauge"
    id={this.props.id}
    data-settings={`{
      "value":${this.state.value},
      "min": 0,
      "max": 100,
      "units": %,
    }`}
    size={this.props.size}
  ></div>
```